# Time Doesn't update in TextView on every Button click.... What's the issue?

Tags: android, time

Time just update for first click... If I click next time It doesn't work. Help me... Question end.

Stack overflow want me to type more details. But this question doesn't need more explanation

I don't know what to add I can't type more for this long it still want me to type something to make the code

Java Code :

```
package com.test.blog.timepicktest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText(c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
        });


    }


}
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.adiraimaji.blog.timepicktest.MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.268"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="82dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Move the `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();` line to inside `onClick()`.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. I never thought I would do the stupid things like that.... :D

Answer (score 1):

`c.get()` does not update calendar date.

you must use `Calendar.getInstance().get(...)` when you handle `onClick`.